# How to get rid of full line tableView separator?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am trying to make only the first and second sections have section titles and make them not float. I added this to cell for row at index path:

```
cell.backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.bounds];
```

and made the tablestyle grouped to prevent the titles from floating. I also made the section footer and header `height` for other sections (one's where I don't want the titles) `CGFLOAT_MIN` and am returning a view of nil for each. How can I get rid of the annoying line below?

[image: The problem]

Answer (score 2):

Rather than trying to use a grouped table view in an unintended why, it's much easier to use a regular table view and disable section header floating. You can do so in one of two ways:

```
CGFloat height = 40.f;
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(self.tableView.bounds), height)];
UIView *dummyView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = dummyView;
self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-dummyViewHeight, 0, 0, 0);
```

Section headers will now scroll just like any regular cell.

Alternately, `UITableView` has two private methods that allow header floating to be enabled/disabled:

```
- (BOOL) allowsHeaderViewsToFloat;
- (BOOL) allowsFooterViewsToFloat;
```

If you are not concerned with using private APIs, just create a `UITableView` subclass and return `NO` for both of these methods.

Comment: Wouldn't that be good for only one section header? I need two. I need one section header for 1 section and another for 25 sections.

Comment: @kishinmanglani Not sure what you mean. Do you want floating headers or no floating headers?

Comment: @kishinmanglani Each section can have whatever header you want. This has nothing to do with floating headers.

Comment: Doesn't the solution you suggested add a headerview to the table itself? I want two sections to have header views, and I want them to be non-floating headers. I also want the second header to act as a header for the other 25 sections. I don't want to repeat the header multiple times. Does that make sense?

Comment: @memmons You made my day thanks a lot. The UITableViewStyleGrouped adds a strange margin in sections and using UITableViewStylePlain was the only way to avoid it, but I didn't want the floating feature.